# what does each runlevel number stand for

Tags: runlevel

Cause Ubuntu uses `Upstart` instead of `init`, there is some different from Red Hat.
But How can I get the list of each runlevel number standing for, such as `init 0` means `shutdown`.
`man init` can't show the list. So which command or man page cant print the list.
Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Try `man telinit`

However, the runlevels in Ubuntu are:

```
Code        Description
0           Halt
1           Single-user mode
2           Graphical multi-user with networking
3-5         Unused but configured the same as runlevel 2
6           Reboot
```

Comment: `man telinit` doesn't list as up. Thx all the same.

Comment: you can easily make runlevels 2-5 mean whatever you want.  i have even added runlevel 7 to my system (reboot via kexec).

Answer (score 1):

The correct runlevels on Ubuntu would be:

```
 Runlevel        Target Units                          Description
 ========================================================================================
     0           runlevel0.target, poweroff.target     Shut down and power off the system.
     1           runlevel1.target, rescue.target       Set up a rescue shell, single user mode.
     2           runlevel2.target, multi-user.target   Set up a non-graphical multi-user system -> - Network, - GUI.
     3           runlevel3.target, multi-user.target   Set up a non-graphical multi-user system -> + Network, - GUI.
     4           runlevel4.target, multi-user.target   Set up a non-graphical multi-user system -> special purposes.
     5           runlevel5.target, graphical.target    Set up a graphical multi-user system -> + Network, + GUI.
     6           runlevel6.target, reboot.target       Shut down and reboot the system.
```

Meaning:

`-`: Absent

`+`: Present

Answer (score 0):

Run levels vary per distribution, but in general:

Runlevel 0: Power off, halted.
Runlevel 1: Single user mode.
Runlevel 6: Reboot.

Usually one of 3,4, or 5 stands for 'multi user', but there is much more variation in these.

Comment: Thx, though you still didn't solve my problem. It seems that I have seen the command to show the whole `runlevel` list before, but can't remember anyway today.

Comment: I can't remember the name either. I usually just search though `/etc/inittab` and use tellinit. That used before upstart arrived.  The closest I come this days is `apt-get install chkconfig` followed by `chkconfig --list service_name`